# conexión Angular y nodeJS a SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, angular, angular6

estoy intentando conectarme a una base de datos SQL server desde un modulo Nodejs.
He probado con autenticación mandandole Usuario y contraseña, y funciona correctamente, pero cuando pruebo con Windows autentication no me funciona.
cuando lano en server.js
Express arrancado en el puerto 5000 arranca asi.
y cuando lanzo el frontEnd hecho con angular no arroja ningun error, simplemente se sale y se queda la consola como al principio, para que meta de nuevo (node server.js)
y en consola me sale
 HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:5000/get-products", ok: false, …}
GET http://localhost:5000/get-products net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

mi codigo de Node JS es

```
   var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
})); // support encoded bodies

// config de la base de datos
var sql = require('mssql//msnodesqlv8');
var config = {

  driver:'msnodesqlv8',
    connectionString: 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=ESMA123\\VS123;Database=Informe;Trusted_Connection=yes;'


};

app.get('/get-products', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    // conexion a bbdd
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query('SELECT * FROM dbo.Map', (err, recordset) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            res.send(recordset);
            sql.close();
        })
    });
});
```

Mi codigo TS:

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';



@Component({
  selector: "app-list-products",
  templateUrl: "./list-products.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./list-products.component.scss"]

})

> export class ListProductsComponent implements OnInit {
> 
> 
>   error: boolean = false;   products: any;   product: any;  
> formGroup: FormGroup;
> 
>   constructor(private http: HttpClient, private formBuilder:
> FormBuilder) {
>     this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({});   }



ngOnInit() {
    this.getProducts();
  }

 getProducts() {
    this.http.get("http://localhost:5000/get-products").subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        this.error = false;
        if (response === null) {
          this.error = true;
          return;
        } else {
          this.products = response;
          console.log("respuesta", response);
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.error = true;
        console.log(
          "Error al recuperar los usuarios de la base de datos",
          error
        );
      }
    );
  }

  loadProduct(p) {
    this.product = p;
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({

      Cliente: p.Cliente,
      Grupo: p.Grupo,
      Socio: p.Socio,
      Gerente: p.Gerente
    });
  }
```

Alguien me puede ayudar?
o bien decirme como hacer este tipo de conexión desde NodeJS a un servidor mediante windows autentication.
muchas gracias de antemando.
un saludo

Comment: debes configurar el cors en tu backend para permitir  a una app cliente acceder a sus funciones

Comment: pero si me funciona con usuaario y contraseña deberia estar configurado no?

Comment: te lo comento porque no lo veo en tu nodejs-express